# Text Mining Using Rapidminer

Tags: nlp, text-mining, rapidminer

I have an excel sheet where every row denotes and issue and its description. One column corresponding to each row denotes details about that issue which is what I want to mine. I want to find out occurrences of each token in each cell and then categorize each row correspondingly(e.g. if a specific token appears more than x times, I will tag that row with that token). When I do it using Rapidminer, it takes all the rows together and tells how many occurrences of each token across all rows rather than taking each row at a time. How can I let Rapidminer take each row at a time and determine for each row the frequency of tokens and apply n grams etc...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using the Process Documents from Data operator with the input coming from the spreadsheet with attributes set to be of type text. Within this operator, there is a Tokenize operator.

If you set the parameter of the Process Documents operator to be "term occurrences" you will get a count of how many times the token appears in the example set.